# Firebase: Uncaught TypeError: Firebase is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, firebase

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot get Firebase to work within this app. I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Firebase is not a constructor
```

When I have:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");
var ref = new Firebase("https://letspretendthisisreal.firebaseio.com");
```

I am using Electron and shame on me I know ... I am not using Angular since I am only building a simple app for only my use. I have spent a good amount of time trying to find the answers online with no luck. You are my only hope!

Comment: That means `Firebase` is not a constructor function, or even a function at all. Are you sure `require()` is returning the firebase constructor

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Recently firebase has updated their web SDK, which changed some of its API. The syntax you're using looks like the 2.x API, while the 3.x is pretty different. Check your package.json to see which version you're using. If it's 3.x, see [the new docs site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) on how to initialize firebase using the new API.

Comment: I have followed the process and even be able to login successfully to my firebase project using firebase CLI. but when i run my node.js, i get an error `PERMISSION_DENIED`