# "Firebase is not a constructor" -- need to downgrade Firebase, how to do it?

Tags: javascript, constructor, firebase, reactjs

I am currently learning React.js from [this course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/learn-and-understand-reactjs/learn/v4/overview). I've reached Lecture 27 and I'm at a standstill. I keep getting the error "Firebase is not a constructor." Just from looking at other people's issues, I've figured out that I need to downgrade Firebase down to V. 2. The only question is, how do I go about doing this?

I went to my app.jsx file and changed Firebase down to "^2.4.2". I also reloaded my entire app. I still get the same error, "Firebase is not a constructor".

Can anyone give me any pointers here? I'd really like to get this app to work. What else do I need to change?

Comment: Do you use npm to handle your dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the firebase by `npm uninstall firebase` then `npm install --save firebase@2.3.2`or @2.2.7 etc, hope i helped (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Im also starting to learn Firebase. Saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313536/firebase-uncaught-typeerror-firebase-is-not-a-constructor) relative to your question. It
    stated that Firebase team updated their web SDK.

Comment: *firebaser here* The existing SDKs will continue to work. There is no *need* to upgrade (although we definitely hope that you will).

Comment: I'm glad to know that the SDKs for V. 2 still work, but do you have any advice on how to downgrade an app that is already on V 3? I'm trying to follow this course as closely as possible so I'd like to go with the version they're using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking the same course and had the same problem. The command `npm install --save firebase` which Stephen (the guy teaching the course) referred to now automatically installs version 3.x of Firebase.

You can just go into the working directory of your project and specify the version of firebase you want to install. He was using v2.3.2 at the time he created the course, so just run the command `npm install --save firebase@2.3.2` and that's what fixed it for me. It will overwrite the v3.x you had previously installed in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I was learning from the Udemy video and had the same issue as yours. I changed Firebase down to `^2.4.2` deleted my `node_modules` and run `npm install` and it worked. Don't forget to delete your `node_modules` and `npm install` it again.